# Bloomberg API: How to get the list of Pricing Sources?

Tags: api, bloomberg

It's possible to get current pricing source for a security (PRICING_SOURCE field). Is there any field that returns the list of all available pricing sources for defined security?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know something about `PRICING_SOURCE`, there are lots of types of securities, concrete ticker returs list of available prices, standing, issuer and historical data, lots of securities doesn't assigned Ticker, there are lots of shares registred only with ISIN, WKN or CEDEL ..., part of private securities has only intial price, big jungle without rulles, consider 1 ) contact Hotline and ask question,  2) all user has own Account manager, some services are hidden in monthly fees, contact her/him, sure depends of BBE version Instales, anywhere, mobile ...

Comment: in Bloomberg terminal I usualy use PCS<GO> command to list the pricing sources. I can use any of it to request HistoricalPrices (e.g. for Corp security). My question is how I can get the list with Bloomber API. I did not find any field that provides such information.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering whether you were able to find a solution to get the list of availiable pricing sources in blp api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - it's not currently possible.

Any *fields* (i.e. visible in **FLDS** in the terminal) are accessible via the API - such as the **PRICING_SOURCE** field in the question.

However, there is currently no functionality like the terminal commands PCS or ALLQ in the API at the moment. There is a request for this functionality with the Bloomberg programmers, and you can contact the Bbg helpdesk to have yourself added to the request to be informed when it becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

Look up your pcs enablements, find the one you want to use /then lock down the eid # from the respective ctrb page. You can request eid specific prices via api.